# iOS UITextView Scrolling Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, terminal, uitextview

I am currently developing a terminal-emulator app for the iPad platform, and am wondering how I can go about removing scrolling-animations from my TextView to make it look and feel like a terminal similar to an old teletype terminal such as the HP700. I want the TextView to maintain an 80x24 character format while scrolling through the text, so the lines "snap" into position rather than smoothly "floating" around like a normal TextView would.

I have tried disabling animations with:
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];

But nothing seems to work....

Comment: I don't think there is any bulid-in featrue that does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at implementing the following properties

```
@property(nonatomic) float decelerationRate
@property(nonatomic) BOOL bounces
```

That should get you started on the proper course.

Comment: Hey thanks, would you mind posting some pseudo-code as an example of how I would use this?

Comment: Okay scratch that, I figured out what you mean. So I disabled deceleration and bouncing, now all I need is to set a constant scroll rate to lock the text into a grid like appearance, as if the text that is "moving" replaces itself with the text above it if that makes sense. For example, if you open up or look at a Unix style terminal, the scrolling mechanism in that is what I'm going for. Would there be any way of doing this?